# Correctly display grid map when two digits involve?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, if-statement, io

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, height;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;
    
    cout << "enter length : ";
    cin >> length;
    
    cout << "enter height : ";
    cin >> height;
    
    for (int row = 0; row <= height+3; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <= length+3; col++)
        {
            if ((col == 0) && (row == 0) || (col == 0) && (row == height+2))
                cout << "h  ";
            else if ((col == 0) && row >= 1 && row < height+3)
                cout << counter++ << "  ";
            else if ((col == 1) && (row == height+3) || (col == length+3) && (row == height+3))
                cout << "q  ";  
            else if ((col >= 2) && row == height+3)
                cout << counter1++ << "  ";
            else if ((row == 0) || (row == (height+2)) || (col == 1) || (col == (length+3)))
                cout << "x  ";
            else
                cout << "   ";
        }
       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

When I insert a length and height of 20, the grid map will not display properly due to 2 digit value. The result become like this:

```
enter length : 13                                                                                                               
enter height : 13                                                                                                               
h  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x                                                                               
0  x                                            x                                                                               
1  x                                            x                                                                               
2  x                                            x                                                                               
3  x                                            x                                                                               
4  x                                            x                                                                               
5  x                                            x                                                                               
6  x                                            x                                                                               
7  x                                            x                                                                               
8  x                                            x                                                                               
9  x                                            x                                                                               
10  x                                            x                                                                              
11  x                                            x                                                                              
12  x                                            x                                                                              
13  x                                            x                                                                              
h  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x                                                                               
   q  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  q
```

The expected result should be:

```
enter length : 13                                                                                                               
enter height : 13                                                                                                               
h  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x                                                                               
0  x                                            x                                                                               
1  x                                            x                                                                               
2  x                                            x                                                                               
3  x                                            x                                                                               
4  x                                            x                                                                               
5  x                                            x                                                                               
6  x                                            x                                                                               
7  x                                            x                                                                               
8  x                                            x                                                                               
9  x                                            x                                                                               
10 x                                            x                                                                              
11 x                                            x                                                                              
12 x                                            x                                                                              
13 x                                            x                                                                              
h  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x                                                                               
   q  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 q
```

I am not sure on how to take care of the 2 digits inputs. Will appreciate if someone can advice on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use manipulators like [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) from the header [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) , as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, height;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;

    cout << "enter length : ";
    cin >> length;

    cout << "enter height : ";
    cin >> height;

    for (int row = 0; row <= height+3; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <= length+3; col++)
        {
            if ((col == 0) && (row == 0) || (col == 0) && (row == height+2))
                cout << "h  ";
            else if ((col == 0) && row >= 1 && row < height+3)
                cout << setw(3)<< left << counter++;
            else if ((col == 1) && (row == height+3) || (col == length+3) && (row == height+3))
                cout << "q  ";
            else if ((col >= 2) && row == height+3)
                cout << setw(3) << left << counter1++;
            else if ((row == 0) || (row == (height+2)) || (col == 1) || (col == (length+3)))
                cout << setw(3) << left  << "x";
            else
                cout << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live](https://rextester.com/GVW6510)

Another thing [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)